# How to execute cmd commands inside an RDP using C# and SSH

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, ssh, command-line

I am trying to make a windows forms app with c#  that should give me normally the ability to connect to an rdp (Remote Desktop protocole) and execute some commands inside it .

I did some researches and I found that I should do it using SSH and for that I de used Renci.ssh package .

in the rdp I installed the open ssh server feature because the OP system is a windows server

and in the app I used the Password Authentication Method but when it try to connect to the rdp it throw an error that say permission denied (password)

I also used the Keyboard Interactive Authentication Method but it didnt work also

I need to know if there is another way to connect to the rdp and excute some commands on it or where I can find the correct username and password of the ssh server

```
try
        {
            AuthenticationMethod method = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username", "password");
            ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo("Ip_Address", "username", method);
            var client = new SshClient(connection);
            if (!client.IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Connected ... ");
                client.Connect();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("already Connected ... ");
            }
        }
catch (Exception ex) {
            richTextBox1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you talk about RDP if you in the end use SSH? Bothe services are totally independent, and they use different protocols. So if you want to establish an SSH connection then do so but then please leave RDP out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Renci does not use RDP. AuthenticationMethod is not required.

```
    try
        {           
            var client = new SshClient(Ip_Address, 22, "username", "password");
            if (!client.IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Connected ... ");
                client.Connect();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("already Connected ... ");
            }
        }
catch (Exception ex) {
        richTextBox1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick but when I use your code it throws and Exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException what is the reason of iyt please ?